# Toshiba A200 very low volume on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, sound, lubuntu, volume-control

A few days ago my Dad decided he was done with Windows on his, pretty old, laptop.
He's got a Toshiba A200-1CN which has the Realtek ALC861-VD sound chip onboard. We decided it would be best to install Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (32-bit). Everything works fine except for the audio.

I have tried the most common stuff I could find on askubuntu like adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

in:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Also changed the model=auto to  model=lenovo and model=toshiba but no luck.

Tried upgrading to Lubuntu 14.10 but nothing changed.

The weird thing is I get audio perfectly fine from the headphone port. It's just the volume of the speakers is extremely low (sounds like 5%). I also tried to open alsa mixer en put all the levels on 100 but that also didn't work unfortunately.

EDIT: Oh and I also tried installing pulse audio but the problem persisted.

EDIT2: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1236
Describes a way to "make" the realtek driver from source. This unfortunately changes nothing
in regards to the audio problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

From your audio setting, and change the

```
Phone Duplex (HSP/HFP)
```

to

```
High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)
```

Comment: Where would these audio settings be located exactly?
To my knowledge, Lubuntu only has alsa mixer and I cannot find anything in there. Are these Ubuntu audio preferences?

Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.

Comment: The only thing I found on the mode for changing Phone Duplex to High Fidelity is on Bluetooth speakers/devices. Since I don't have any I can't change it?

Comment: Trying to bump this question a bit because I cannot get this issue resolved. Tried this new method as of yesterday. 
http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1236

Unfortunately this did also not work and I have searched high and low to find the suggestion given by vembutech. If someone has the a golden tip it would be much appreciated ;)